# Wrong data set in the database

Tags: c#, db2

I have a method, to update a record in the **DB2** database:

```
private void updateRecord()
{
    String query = String.Format(@"  UPDATE {0}
        SET CCDESC = @CCdesc, 
            CCSDSC = @CCsdsc, 
            CCNOT1 = @CCnot1, 
            CCNOT2 = @CCnot2,
            CCUDC1 = @CCUdC1,
            CCUDC2 = @CCudc2,
            CCUDC3 = @CCudc3,
            CCRESV = @CCresv,
            CCMNDT = @CCMNDT,
            CCMNTM = @CCMNTM,
            CCMNUS = @User
        WHERE CCTabl = @CCTabl AND CCCode = @CCCode"
       , table);
    Dictionary<String, Object> para = new Dictionary<String, Object>()
        {
            {"@CCTabl", OLDDetail.TableID},
            {"@CCCode", OLDDetail.primaryCode},
            {"@CCdesc", detail.tableDescription},
            {"@CCsdsc", detail.shortDescription} ,
            {"@CCnot1", detail.note1},
            {"@CCnot2", detail.note2}, 
            {"@CCUdC1", detail.udc1} ,
            {"@CCudc2", detail.udc2} ,
            {"@CCudc3", detail.udc3} ,
            {"@CCresv", detail.reservation},
            {"@CCMNDT", detail.maintainedDate},
            {"@CCMNTM", detail.maintainedTime},
            {"@User", this.user.username}
        };
    database.executeQuery(query, para);
}
```

When I look in the database, the field '**CCMNUS**' has the same value that '**CCMNDT**' has. I don't see why this happens.

This is the method to write to the server:

```
        public void executeQuery(String query, Dictionary<String, Object> para)
    {
        database.con.Open();
        using (database.cmd = new iDB2Command(query, database.con))
        {
            database.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            foreach (var value in para)
            {
                database.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(value.Key, value.Value);
            }
            database.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        database.con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: have you double checked the values you are passing to detail.maintainedDate and this.use.username ? or try debug and check the values on your foreach loop.

Comment: It seems strange because the DB2 provider supports named parameters but the only thing that comes to mind is the different order of the parameters added to the dictionary versus the order defined by the placeholders. Try to move the first two keys of the dictionary as last to follow exactly the order of the placeholders

Comment: Yes, the values are correct, I checked it a couple of times, also with other results, I have to less reputation to post a picture, otherwise had post it

Comment: Oh nice, Steve that did the trick, but it's not clear why it happend?
Because the field scrambled it up was 2 fields back...

Comment: Where is `table` coming from?  I'm asking just to make sure you're not open to SQL Injection.

Comment: table is just a readonly String because the entire class make use of this table.